# Select two equally-sized disjoint subarrays, A and B, that maximise the sum (A_1*B_k + A_2*B_(k-1) ... + A_k*B_1), k = |A| = |B|

Tags: java, algorithm

A food fest is organised at the JLN stadium. The stalls from different states and cities have been set up. To make the fest more interesting, multiple games have been arranged which can be played by the people to win the food vouchers.One such game to win the food vouchers is described below:

There are N number of boxes arranged in a single queue. Each box has an integer I written on it. From the given queue, the participant has to select two contiguous subsequences A and B of the same size. The selected subsequences should be such that the summation of the product of the boxes should be maximum. The product is not calculated normally though. To make the game interesting, the first box of subsequence A is to be multiplied by the last box of subsequence B. The second box of subsequence A is to be multiplied by the second last box of subsequence B and so on. All the products thus obtained are then added together.

If the participant is able to find the correct such maximum summation, he/she will win the game and will be awarded the food voucher of the same value.

Note: The subsequences A and B should be disjoint.

Example:

Number of boxes, N = 8

The order of the boxes is provided below:

***1  9  2  3  0  6  7  8***

Subsequence A

***9 2 3***

Subsequence B

***6 7 8***

The product of the subsequences will be calculated as below:

P1 = 9 * 8 = 72

P2 = 2 * 7 = 14

P3 = 3 * 6 = 18

Summation, S = P1 + P2 + P3 = 72 + 14 + 18 = 104

This is the maximum summation possible as per the requirement for the given N boxes.

Tamanna is also in the fest and wants to play this game. She needs help in winning the game and is asking for your help. Can you help her in winning the food vouchers?

Input Format

The first line of input consists of the number of boxes, N.

The second line of input consists of N space-separated integers.

Constraints

1< N <=3000

-10^6 <= I <=10^6

Output Format
Print the maximum summation of the product of the boxes in a separate line.

Sample TestCase 1
input

```
8
1 9 2 3 0 6 7 8
```

output

```
104
```

my code is this it is passing only one test can anyone tell me what is wrong and i don't have other test cases since they r hidden

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    static class pair {
        int first, second;
        
        public pair(int first, int second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
    }
    
    static int getSubarraySum(int sum[], int i, int j) {
        if (i == 0)
            return sum[j];
        else
            return (sum[j] - sum[i - 1]);
    }
    
    static int maximumSumTwoNonOverlappingSubarray(int arr[], int N,
            int K) {
        int l = 0, m = 0;
        int a1[] = new int[N / 2];
        int a2[] = new int[N / 2];
        int prod = 0;
        int[] sum = new int[N];
        sum[0] = arr[0];
        
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
            sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + arr[i];
        
        pair resIndex = new pair(N - 2 * K, N - K);
        
        int maxSum2Subarray =
                getSubarraySum(sum, N - 2 * K, N - K - 1)
                        + getSubarraySum(sum, N - K, N - 1);
        
        pair secondSubarrayMax =
                new pair(N - K, getSubarraySum(sum, N - K, N - 1));
        
        for (int i = N - 2 * K - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int cur = getSubarraySum(sum, i + K, i + 2 * K - 1);
            if (cur >= secondSubarrayMax.second)
                secondSubarrayMax = new pair(i + K, cur);
            cur = getSubarraySum(sum, i, i + K - 1)
                    + secondSubarrayMax.second;
            if (cur >= maxSum2Subarray) {
                maxSum2Subarray = cur;
                resIndex = new pair(i, secondSubarrayMax.first);
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = resIndex.first; i < resIndex.first + K; i++) {
            a1[l] = arr[i];
            l++;
        }
        
        for (int i = resIndex.second; i < resIndex.second + K; i++) {
            a2[m] = arr[i];
            m++;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (a1[i] != 0 || a2[i] != 0) {
                prod = prod + a1[i] * a2[m - (i + 1)];
            }
        }
        return prod;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int k = 0;
        int arr[] = new int[a];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        int l = arr.length;
        int ar[] = new int[a / 2];
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= a / 2; i++) {
            ar[k] = maximumSumTwoNonOverlappingSubarray(arr, l, i);
            k++;
        }
        
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        System.out.println(ar[k - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary language tags. Also, could you add a description of these tests, and which ones you passed/failed (including what you got)?

Comment: i don't have other test cases since they are hidden and the first and only test case is written in already as Sample TestCase 1

Comment: How can you decide on the best subarrays for `a1` and `a2` without calculating `prod`? That makes sense, since the sum of a subarray has little to do with the value of the product sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    
#include <iostream>

#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template<class T> inline void umax(T &a,T b){if(a<b) a = b ; }

template<class T> inline void umin(T &a,T b){if(a>b) a = b ; }

template<class T> inline T abs(T a){return a>0 ? a : -a;}

template<class T> inline T gcd(T a,T b){return __gcd(a, b);}

template<class T> inline T lcm(T a,T b){return a/gcd(a,b)*b;}

typedef long long ll;

typedef pair<int, int> ii;

const int inf = 1e9 + 143;

const ll longinf = 1e18 + 143;

inline int read()

{

int x;scanf(" %d",&x);

return x;

}

const int N = 20001;

int n;

int a[N];

void read_inp()

{

   n = read();

   assert(1 <= n && n <= 20000);

   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)

{

       a[i] = read();

       assert(abs(a[i]) <= int(1e6));

   }

}

int main()

{

#ifdef KAZAR

   freopen("f.input","r",stdin);

   freopen("f.output","w",stdout);

   freopen("error","w",stderr);

#endif

   read_inp();

   ll ans = -longinf;

   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)

{

       {

           int l = i - 1, r = i;

           ll best = 0ll, cur = 0ll;

           while(l >= 1 && r <= n)

  {

               ll val = (ll)a[l] * a[r];

               cur += val;

               umin(best, cur);

               umax(ans, cur - best);

               --l;

               ++r;

           }

       }

 {

           int l = i - 1, r = i + 1;

           ll best = 0ll, cur = 0ll;

           while(l >= 1 && r <= n)

  {

               ll val = (ll)a[l] * a[r];

               cur += val;

               umin(best, cur);

               umax(ans, cur - best);

               --l;

               ++r;

           }

       }

   }

   printf("%lld\n",ans);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: This the answer you are looking for, this question is for Capgemini Tech Challenge 2020.

Comment: could you please explain your algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `O(n^2)` time, `O(1)` space solution.

Lets write all `O(n^2)` multiples in a matrix. For example:

```
Input {1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6}

    1   2   3  -4   5   6
 1  x   2   3  -4   5   6
 2      x   6  -8  10  12
 3          x -12  15  18
-4              x -20 -24
 5                  x  30
 6                      x
```

Now pick any indexes `(i, j), i ≠ j`, say `(0, 5)`.

```
                          j
      1   2   3  -4   5   6
i  1  x   2   3  -4   5   6
   2      x   6  -8  10  12
   3          x -12  15  18
  -4              x -20 -24
   5                  x  30
   6                      x
```

Now imagine we wanted to find the best subarray where `i` was first, then second, then third, etc. of a valid selection. In each iteration, we would increment `i` and decrement `j`, such that we move on the diagonal: `6, 10, -12`, each time adding the multiple to extend our selection.

We can do this on each of the diagonals to get the best selection starting on `(i, j)`, where `i` is first, then second, then third, etc.

Now imagine we ran [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm) on each of the diagonals from northeast to southwest (up to where the `x`s are where `i = j`). Complexity `O(n^2)` time. (There's Python code in one of the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64532360/revisions).)

Comment: How does this enforce the constraint that the subarrays are disjoint?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'm looking at the top-right triangle (above the `x`s) that I provided an example of and see no overlap. Am I missing something? There's also python code in the answer revisions that I'm pretty sure does not overlap but would welcome your input. (I added that caveat to the end of the answer.)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat maybe I wasn't clear enough on *which* diagonals :) I'll add that.

Comment: Oh, I see -- the B array is reversed.

Comment: Sorry but i am not that good in code can u give me the code of ur explanation @גלעדברקן

Comment: @adnanahmed I did provide code. The very last sentence in my answer contains a link that will take you there :)

Comment: @גלעד ברקן
Hello! I used a similar algorithm but it didn't pass the test cases. I tried yours too. It didn't pass either. The question is from a contest.

Comment: @Shubhashish please provide a link to the contest. If you have an issue with the algorithm, please provide specific details about the issue.

Comment: I believe the contest has already ended and heard that this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64693207/9380247 worked. Contest link: https://techchallenge.in.capgemini.com/campus-challenge

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
res=0
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
re=[]
while(True):
    if(len(l)==2):
        pass
        break
    else:
        n1=l[1]
        n2=l[-1]
        re.append(n1*n2)
        l.remove(n1)
        l.remove(n2)
for i in re:
    res=res+i
print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code

```
int main(){

int n;
cin>>n;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    cin>>arr[i];
int dp[n][n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {

        if(j==i) 
            dp[i][j]=0;
        else if(j<i)
            dp[i][j]=0;
        else 
            dp[i][j]=arr[i]*arr[j];
    }

}
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cout<<dp[i][j]<<"   ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;
//find max sum diagonal
long long int global_sum=0;

//get sum of diagonal increasing i
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    long long int curr_sum=0;
    int j=i;
    int k=n-1;
    while(k>=0 && j<n){
        curr_sum+=dp[j][k];
        k--;
        j++;
    }
    if(curr_sum>global_sum) global_sum=curr_sum;

}
//get sum with decreasing i
for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    long long int curr_sum=0;
    int j=i;
    int k=0;
    while(k<n && j>=0){
        curr_sum+=dp[j][k];
        j--;
        k++;
    }
    if(curr_sum>global_sum) global_sum=curr_sum;
}
cout<<global_sum;}
```

This code passes the testcase you gave and other testcases i tried myself. Its O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: When answering, you should explain why this code works, in particular what OP was doing wrong.

Comment: This solution seems to take O(n^2) space. But there's no need for that. We can [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64532360/2034787) it with O(1) extra space.